# Garageband only recognizes one plugin of three installed

Tags: macos, audio, music, garageband, plugins

I have three plugins installed in `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components` however Garageband only finds the first one I installed, Crystal. The others, Synth1 and TAL-Bassline are ignored, even when I restart Garageband. Crystal works fine, and is available.

Has anyone else come across this? What should I do?

---

I have Garageband 10.0.3 running on OSX 10.9.5. All plugins are AU (.component) plugins.

---

Update: This is the what shows up in console when Garageband starts up (this is all of it; there's no filter):

```
5/11/15 12:37:27.595 PM MIDIServer[5093]: 12:37:27.594 NOTE:      [0x7fff75d32310] MIDIServer.cpp:353: FullInit: MIDIServer [5093] starting; arch=x86_64
5/11/15 12:37:28.665 PM GarageBand[5082]: Application with BundleID "com.apple.ImpulseResponseUtility" is not present on this system
5/11/15 12:37:31.447 PM GarageBand[5082]: Invalid color System, labelColor (warning given only once)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What plugin-type are they?
GarageBand will only use AU plugins, with a .component extension, it can't use VST etc.

Each plugin type ought to be in its correct sub-folder - Components, Digidesign, HAL, VST etc

See
[Interface types explained (VST, RTAS, AU, etc.)](http://support.pluginboutique.com/knowledgebase/articles/51119-interface-types-explained-vst-rtas-au-etc)
[Finding Audio Units plug-ins on your computer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201532) &
[How to Install plugins for Garageband - Add Audio Unit Filters to Garage band (AU)](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Install-plugins-for-Garageband-Add-Audio-/)

You can force the AU cache to rebuild by deleting the cache file in `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.audiounits.cache` while GarageBand is not running, then launch it again

Comment: They are all AU plugins, in the component folder.

Comment: afaik, both Synth1 & TAL-Bassline are only available as VSTi. Do they have a .component extension, or .vst or…?

Comment: Yes, they have a component extension just as I say in my question.

Comment: Then it would be interesting to know where they came from… see http://www.kvraudio.com/product/synth1-by-ichiro-toda and http://kunz.corrupt.ch/products/tal-bassline

Comment: ah, OK - ichi added AU more recently - http://www.geocities.jp/daichi1969/softsynth/ - apologies

Comment: added cache clear info

Comment: Still no joy :( Good tip, though.

Comment: …then the next thing to do would be clear the cache again, open Console & watch what is reported as Garageband attempts to reload the plugins. If you've only 4 [plus the built-in ones, unfortunately] it oughtn't to be quite so painful as the several hundred I watched it go through yesterday, whilst researching this… I'm guessing it still will not be a fun 15 mins - but the chances are it will have looked at them & dismissed them for some logical reason.

Comment: Thanks. As it happens, no such cache file has been created by running Garageband. I'll check out what console shows, and update my question.

Comment: Updated. Nothing very illuminating, sadly.

Comment: There should have been reams of data - maybe try running the auval tool independently, from terminal [not something I'm particularly adept with ;) but try `auval -a -q` which should only output errors & a list of 'type' codes, like 'aufx OKWX ksWV'

Comment: I did this (with and without -q) and it only shows the plugins which Bandcamp knows about (i.e. not the ones I'm having trouble with and also including the apple ones).

Comment: Also I zapped ~/marcin/Library/Caches/AudioUnitCache/* to no avail.

Comment: I've tried Synth1, it fails validation [I can view the results in Logic, which Garageband doesn't show you]. I cannot find an AU version of TAL to test.

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting. Can you post the output/talk about what the failure is?

Comment: nothing more than 'failed validation'. It doesn't give details

Comment: Why does it have a VST folder if it can't use VST's

Comment: `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/` isn't only for Garageband, it's for any/all audio usage.